# How to predict sales with only sporadic, occasional, marketing costs in time series?

Tags: predictive-models, stationarity

I want to predict my sales using my marketing costs, but my marketing costs data has a lot of zero expenditure days. Both sales and marketing data are daily observe data but I only spend on the marketing side infrequently, i.e., I have zero values on a lot of observed days.

Comment: I would imagine that marketing expenditures are for *distributed* types of results, e.g. pay for an ad that then runs for days or weeks? I am not sure if you need stationarity to do prediction. Some sort of "integrated form" of the marketing costs could be used perhaps? For example, a convolution with an "[impulse response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_response)" kernel?

Comment: Yup, that kind of data, like the pays for ads. I am not sure what you meant with integrated form, though.

Comment: I was not certain of the question context, and a lot of econometric time-series questions seem to focus on stationarity and differencing/integrating time series to achieve this. So I crudely meant "integrate" in the sense of "smoothing" the response (vs. differencing, which tends to "roughen"). Really more the idea of a lagged & distributed response though, as in the impulse response link I gave.

Comment: Just read the full article, thanks for this. never thought my signal processing course will be this helpful. Thank you.

Comment: I just posted an answer summarizing these comments. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I would imagine that marketing expenditures are for distributed types of results, e.g. you pay for an ad that then runs for days or weeks? This suggests a lagged & distributed respons of sales to a given marketing expenditure. This could perhaps be represented by convolution with an "[impulse response](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impulse_response)" kernel.

Commonly "stationarity" is considered in the context of [ARIMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_integrated_moving_average) models. This approach should be applicable here, as I believe these models can represent convolutions. However you would have to use the multivariate version. I cannot say what tools would be best to estimate this sort of model, but [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/94443/is-there-any-tool-that-can-do-vector-arima-modeling-in-time-series) is one place to start.

Comment: I agree, that is what I would do. +1